# Shapes must be equal rank

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to do transfer learning from a pre-trained model. I'm following the [guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) for retrain from Tensorflow.

However, I'm stuck in an error `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 3 and 2 for 'input_1/BottleneckInputPlaceholder' (op: 'PlaceholderWithDefault') with input shapes: [1,?,128].`

```
# Last layer of pre-trained model 
# `[<tf.Tensor 'embeddings:0' shape=(?, 128) dtype=float32>]`

with tf.name_scope('input'):
    bottleneck_input = tf.placeholder_with_default(
        bottleneck_tensor,
        shape=[None, 128],
        name='BottleneckInputPlaceholder')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the shape of `bottleneck_tensor`? And could you also print the shape of `bottleneck_input` after you define it?

Comment: it's the last layer of pretrained model, which is listed as "embeddings:0 shape=(?, 128)"

Comment: Yes, but I think your problem is `bottleneck_tensor`'s shape. It seems that one has an extra dimension prepended

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `bottleneck_tensor` is of shape `[1, ?, 128]` and you are explicitly stating that the shape should be `[?, 128]`. You can use [`tf.squeeze`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) to reduce convert your tensor in the required shape as

```
tf.squeeze(bottleneck_tensor)
```